# Select QTableView row from a model index

Tags: qt, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

In my Qt 6.6.0 application I set up a `QSqlTableModel` and a `QTableView` with sorting enabled:

```
QSqlTableModel *model;
model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
model->setTable("table");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->sort(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
model->select();

ui->tableDb->setModel(model); // QTableView
```

I add a record in this way:

```
QSqlRecord record = model->record();
record.setValue("col1", value1);
// ...

for (int i = 0; i < record.count(); i++) record.setGenerated(i, true);
bool ret = true;
ret &= _model->insertRecord(-1, record);
ret &= _model->submitAll();
if (!ret) return false;

ui->tableDb->selectRow(???);
```

I want to select the row of the last inserted record.
Since I have sorting enabled, I don't know where the record is placed in the `QTableView`.

How to retrieve its "visual" position from the model index?

Looking at the `QTableView` [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html) I found nothing relevant.
There is a `scrollTo()` function but it just ensures the record is visible, not selected.
I'm looking for something like a `QTableView::selectRow(const QModelIndex &index)` function...

Comment: An empty record inserted with `-1` should always be shown at the last row of the view, no matter the sorting. Use the view's [`selectionModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel). Just retrieve the index of the first column in the last row (`rowCount() - 1`) and then call the `selectionModel()->select(index, flags)`, with `flags` including `SelectCurrent` and `Rows`.

Comment: @musicamante it is actually shown on the correct position. It's not an empty record, by the way

Comment: Sorry, I missed the line with `setValue()`. I've never used `insertRecord` in a sorted QSqlTableModel, but since you're probably always adding new rows/record manually, one thing you could do is to connect the `rowsInserted` signal of the model to a function that does what suggested above. Obviously, you should only do that once, and probably as soon as the model has been set on the table *and* it has already been populated with `select()`. Eventually, look into the `primeInsert` signal, but I'm afraid it will be emitted *before* `rowsInserted`, which may not be fine.

Comment: @musicamante the `rowsInserted` signal confirms the inserted record is actually the last row, as expected. The problem is `tableView->selectionModel()->select(index, flags)` actually selects the last row in the view, not the row in the view that correspond to the last row in the model!

Comment: So, I suppose that inserting a new record just "resets" the model (similarly to calling `select()` again), and sorting invalidates the current persistent indexes. But that's just a wild assumption. I see that you choose to switch to a QSortFilterProxyModel, which would've been my next suggestion. Generally, it's preferable, even if it's not the most intuitive choice and may add some overhead for very large models.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a `QSortFilterProxyModel`:

```
QSqlTableModel *model;
QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel;

model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
model->setTable("table");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->select();

proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
proxyModel->sort(0);
ui->tableDb->setModel(proxyModel);

// ...

QModelIndex index = proxyModel->mapFromSource(model->index(model->rowCount() - 1, 0));
ui->tableDb->selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex(index, QItemSelectionModel::SelectCurrent | QItemSelectionModel::Rows);
```

In this way I can retrieve the correct `QModelIndex` of the `QTableView` from the index of the `QSqlTableModel`.